# How do I RELIABLY get path to vscode User directory from extension?

Tags: path, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

**User** is a directory that contains: **snippets.json**, **keybindings.json**, **settings.json**...

`Mac`/`Windows`/`Linux` OS

`System`/`User` level installation

`Stable`/`Insiders`/`Exploration`/`OSS`

installs all have different paths.

I want to get it just like `vscode.env.appRoot` works. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```typescript
const UserDirectoryPath = path.join(extensionContext.logPath, '../../../..', 'User');
```

Answer (score 0):

In you activation function for your extension you'll get an `ExtensionContext` instance, which has a property `extensionPath`.

Comment: I think he's asking for the directory where `keybindings.json`, `settings.json` etc are located.

Comment: Yes, this answer is an entirely different directory. But I completely forgot about ExtensionContext - going to try to get path from there.