# How to find user-data-dir from an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to find user-data-dir from an extension?
If vscode is opened with --user-data-dir option, is there a way to find this value from an extension? I need to find the location of settings.json in use from our extension.

Comment: Is there an environment variable you can check, like `LOCALAPPDATA` or `APPDATA` from `const envs = process.env;`  that changes depending on whether the CLI option `--user-data-dir` is used?

Comment: highly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53990800/11107541

Comment: I wonder why would you need to know the location of `settings.json`. I mean, if you need to read or update settings, the `getConfiguration` API would work just fine, no matter the location of `settings.json`.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but one way would be to get the path of something that's *in* the user data directory, and then just walk upward. Ex. `globalStoragePath` or `globalStorageUri` from an [`ExtensionContext`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext), which gives you a [`Uri`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Uri) of the user data dir with `globalStorage/<extension ID lowercase>` to the path. See also NodeJS's `path.resolve`. Ex.

```
const path = require("path");
const userDataDir = path.resolve(extensionContext.globalStoragePath, "../..");
```